# Can we apply aggregate functions in the select clause (getting error: not a single-group group function)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query in which I am trying to get a column by subtracting total of one column - other but I am getting error. Here's what I am doing

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.", 
       CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "Business Unit",
       ....
        sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) - DOCS_DISB_SIGN_OFF_LOG.sign_off_amt AS "Amount Not Disbursed",
       ...
from
    losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN
    code_branch CODE_BRANCH
ON
    LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
...
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status='A'; -- Application Status in {‘accepted’}
```

But I am getting error that

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8
```

How can i accomplish this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ORA-00937:**  not a single-group group function

**Cause:**  A SELECT list cannot include both a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, and an individual column expression, unless the individual column expression is included in a GROUP BY clause.

**Action:** Drop either the group function or the individual column expression from the SELECT list or add a GROUP BY clause that includes all individual column expressions listed.

https://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-00937%3A+not+a+single-group+group+function&oq=ORA-00937%3A+not+a+single-group+group+function&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.", 
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "Business Unit",
   ....
    sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) - DOCS_DISB_SIGN_OFF_LOG.sign_off_amt AS "Amount Not Disbursed",
   ...
 from
   losa_app LOSA_APP

 INNER JOIN
   code_branch CODE_BRANCH
 ON
   LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
   ...
 GROUP BY LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, LOSA_APP.app_ref_no
 HAVING  LOSA_APP.app_status='A'; -- Application Status in {‘accepted’}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why did you use two same tables in the group by clause `GROUP BY LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, LOSA_APP.app_ref_no` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if there is one sign_off for every amt_appr:

```
sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr - DOCS_DISB_SIGN_OFF_LOG.sign_off_amt)
```

or this trick, where the AVG of a repeated value is the repeated value:

```
sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) - AVG(DOCS_DISB_SIGN_OFF_LOG.sign_off_amt)
```

Comment: No in both cases i am getting the same error :(. I think i should use `LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr - DOCS_DISB_SIGN_OFF_LOG.sign_off_amt AS "Amount Not Disbursed",` in the select clause ? by the way is it possible to use aggregate function in the select clause?